# Defeating audio spyware with low-tech

Tags: spyware, audio

Malware can target camera and microphone and make them secretly record what's going on around the laptop. However, defeating camera spyware can easily be done with a piece of tape, something the [FBI chief recommends people to do](https://www.engadget.com/2016/09/15/fbi-chief-james-comey-webcam-tape/).

But, is there any similar low-tech, preferably foolproof and reasonable approach to protecting against spyware audio recording? Physically removing the microphone? Wrapping tin foil around the laptop? (I'm using Windows.)

---

<sup>A [similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124216/how-to-know-if-my-laptop-microphone-is-recording-automatically) exists, but it concerns Linux only.</sup>

Comment: Destroying the internal mic, and having an external one which you plug only when you actually use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a VICE interview Snowden removes a mobile phones internal speakers, then plugs a headphone set in when he wants to actually have a conversation.

Short of precision de-soldering you could try to jam it up with something, I don't believe new microphones in laptops and mobile phones have a diaphragm but you could at least muffle the speaker by pushing glue up against it.

Some laptops and mobile devices may on a hardware level disable the on-board microphone when an external line in is plugged in to the microphone jack, so you could plug in a dummy microphone to stop it listening.